# Bitwise Operators file function php

Tags: php, image, bitwise-operators

Can someone explain me how this function works?

```
    $size=100 //kb
    if (filesize(file) > ($size << 10))
     echo "file too big";
```

How does `$size << 10` work? How can I make it use MB instead of KB?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The expression `$size << 10` shifts the bit pattern to the left 10 times, effectively multiplying by 1024; In other words, it's `$size * 1024`.

Every time you perform a left shift, you multiply the value by a factor of two. See also [bitwise operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php).

If you want `$size` to mean size in MB, you multiply by another 1024, i.e.

```
if ($filesize($file) > $size * 1024 * 1024) {
    echo "file too big";
}
```

Or:

```
if ($filesize($file) > $size << 20) {
    echo "file too big";
}
```

Comment: Left shift and dividing, what?

Comment: @Jack i suggest you read the docs carefully. "Shift the bits of $a $b steps to the left (each step means "multiply by two")"

Comment: @TimWolla if I can would like to accept both answers Jack explain better how convert to M and you how function Bitwise operator thanks

Comment: @TimWolla I don't think he can yet, but I will :)

Comment: @TimWolla I'm afraid but min reputation is 15

Answer (score 3):

Numbers are internally represented as binary, a series of zeroes and ones. The `<<` operator will shift all the binary digits left by the specified amount of places, on the right it appends zeroes, example:

```
  7 << 2
= 111 << 2 (7 = 111 in base two)
= 11100
= 28 (11100 = 28 in base ten)
```

---

The next you need to know that `1024 = 2`<sup>`10`</sup> and therefore has a `10` digit binary representation, therefore shifting left by 10 digits results in the number being multiplied by `1024`.

Answer (score 1):

`$size << 10` means `$size * pow(2, 10)`. Tenth power of `2` is `1024`, which is number of bytes in a kilobyte. Number of bytes in a megabyte is `pow(2, 20)`; you could write it as `$size << 20`.

Answer (score 0):

The filesize function returns the size of the file in **bytes**. The `$size` value is defined as **KB**. `($size << 10)` converts from KB to bytes so that the comparison is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It's a left shift operator.

`100 << 10` means shift 100 to the left by 10. That gives you `102400`

It's the same as multiplying by 1024.

It's converting 100kb to bytes, which is what the `filesize()` returns.